# How to derive functional dependencies from a table

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I have a homework that is try to derive the functional dependencies of a table, which is from [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Car+Evaluation). There are seven attributes named [A-G], and in the tabel, all combinations of attributes [A-F] is listed in the table and the last column G is depended on columns [A-F].
So how to derive functional dependencies?
I try to mine the relationship by brute-force method and find only all the six attributes given that can determine the last attribute. Does someone have any good idea ?

Comment: Derive the dependencies based on what? You say that {ABCDEF}->{G}. Are you expected to derive the closure from that one dependency? Or is {ABCDEF}->{G} just your conclusion based on the example data?

Comment: Based on the table, all I have is  the dataset. And I only find a FD {ABCDEF}->{G} on the dataset, I wonder whether have some other FDs.  Notice that I have the dataset which covers all the attributes space.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the functional dependency `ABCDEF → G` is the only non-trivial dependency that is present in your data.

This can be proved by brute force, since for equal values of each different combination of attributes, we can always found different values for each of the remaining attributes.

Since this is the only dependency found by mining the data, no other dependency is possible, a part from the obvious trivial dependencies, `X → Y`, for each combination of attributes `X`, with `Y ⊆ X`.

Answer (score 0):

Given some FDs that hold, all the FDs that can be derived via Armstrong's axioms also hold.

If you know that the only FDs that hold are the ones that hold when some given ones hold, ie that the given ones form a cover, then Armstrong's axioms give you all the FDs that hold.